# How get location (Latitude, Longitude) in center of map Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, openstreetmap

I'm in a project with Xamarin Forms and OpenStreetMap.
I'm trying get the coordinates in the center of map.

This my code that create the map

```
public static Map CreateMap(double latitud, double longitud)
{
   map = new Map();
   var location = new Point(longitud, latitud);
   var sphericalMercatorCoordinate = SphericalMercator.FromLonLat(location.X, location.Y);
   map.Layers.Add(OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());
   map.Home = n => n.NavigateTo(sphericalMercatorCoordinate, map.Resolutions[15]);
   return map;
}
```

This is my code in file xaml.

```
<maps:MapView x:Name="MapView"
              TouchMove="MapView_TouchMove"
              MyLocationFollow="True"
              IsMyLocationButtonVisible="False" 
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Try adding a method "TouchMove". But only get Bounds of map and not the coordinate.

```
private void MapView_TouchMove(object sender, Mapsui.UI.TouchedEventArgs e)
{
    var center = MapView.Bounds.Center;
}
```

So, try add a Method MapClicked, for invoke this method from "MapView_TouchMove" but i dont know how invoke.

```
private void MapView_MapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var lat = e.Point.Latitude;
}
```

Any idea..???
Thanks.

Comment: it would be helpful if you linked to the actual map control that you are using

Comment: Added my code that create the map. I using OpenStreetMap

Comment: I know you're using OpenStreetMap.  I assume you're using some Nuget package for the control, I'm asking you to provide a link to it

Comment: https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui - Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

looking at the API docs, [Envelope](http://mapsui.com/api/Mapsui.Map.html#Mapsui_Map_Envelope) appears to return what you want

> Gets the extents of the map based on the extents of all the layers in
> the layers collection

The `MapView` control has a `Map` property, from which you can get `Envelope`

Answer (score 0):

I got it using the Viewport property of the Navigator:

```
var vp = _mapControl.Map?.Navigator.Viewport;

MapCentre = new MPoint(vp.Value.CenterX, vp.Value.CenterY);
x = vp.Value.CenterX;
y = vp.Value.CenterY;

var LonLat = SphericalMercator.ToLonLat(x, y);

Longitude = LonLat.lon;
Latitude = LonLat.lat;
```